# OSM Overpass: get parent polygon

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Is it possible to get the parent polygon of a relation, way or node?

For example:
This beach is inside this island. And the Island is inside a National Park. And the National park is inside a country, etc.

Can I get the closest surrounding polygon out of OSM with the [Overpass Api](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/blI)?

Example, this beach is inside the island:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer.

This query will get all the polygons it lies in. From the smallest to the largest (country). Where "317086850" is the Osm id. ([Test it here](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/bmI))

```
way(317086850);
>;
is_in;
out;
```

But this is not sufficient. If (for example) a beach lies on an island, but the polygon overlaps the island border for a tiny bit. The query above will not get it. So I use this query to get all border shares. Which will come up with the island. ([Test it here](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/bmJ))

```
way(317086850)->.boundaryways;
way[natural](around.boundaryways:0);
(._; - way.boundaryways[natural];);
(._; - way.boundaryways[place];);
out geom;
```